# Facebook Page - Adding an App

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-page

I know it's quite a popular question but my case seems to be a bit different (as far as I can see).

I am trying to add an app to my page. It is really straightforward, I just used the well known url:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=xxx&next=xxx

The problem I have it the way the app is linked to. The current URL looks like:

https://www.facebook.com/pages/xxxx/1234567890?id=1234567890&sk=app_9887654321

The way I would like it to look like is the same way as other popular fan pages do (i.e Coca Cola, Red Bull) - facebook.com/xxxx/pp_9887654321

I hope it makes sense.

Looking forward to hearing from you.

M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to take username (short url) for your page. After it, automatically your tab apps will be renamed. To get username, you have to have at least 25 fans. If you do, just check out this url: http://www.facebook.com/username